# In surface view audio plays before video starts

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

Surfaceview audio problem. The audio plays before the video starts. therefore two audio sounds is heard in the video.

Any suggestion for this problem

thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you waiting for the Surface to be created before you start playback?

Comment: i want the video must starts when fragment creates the surface.. there is delay in the launch of the activity.. that's why audio plays before video and two audio sounds is heard in the video.